# UIScrollView buttons not receiving touch events

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am using auto layout and brian voong's `.anchor` utility function from his [lets build that app.com](https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/) tutorials.

I have searched extensively for **buttons not receiving touch events** when contained in a `UIScrollView` and have tried:

1) Subclassing `UIScrollView` and override `touchesShouldCancel`:

```
class RUIScrollView:UIScrollView {
    override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

2) Explicitly enabling user interaction on said button, bringing it to the front (I have tried `scrollview.bringSubvew(toFront:UIView)`, `containerViewbringSubvew(toFront:UIView)`, and `view.bringSubvew(toFront:UIView)`)

```
class AboutViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1500)
        scrollView.bringSubview(toFront: conferenceInfoButton)
        conferenceInfoButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


    }

    let scrollView:RUIScrollView = {
        let sv = RUIScrollView()
            //tried true and false for all the following properties:
        sv.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        sv.isScrollEnabled = true
        sv.delaysContentTouches = true 
        sv.canCancelContentTouches = true
        return sv
    }()

    let conferenceInfoButton: LeftAlignedIconButton = {
       let button = LeftAlignedIconButton()
       button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
       button.backgroundColor = UIColor.rutgersRed
       button.setTitle("Conference Info", for: UIControlState.normal)
       button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 21)
       button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
       button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
       button.isUserInteractionEnabled  = true
       button.setImage(UIImage(named: "logo_collaborate"), for: UIControlState.normal)
       button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
       button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, 0)
       return button
    }()
    ...
}
```

**My view hierarchy and constraints:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.backgroundColor
    scrollView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

    containerView.addSubview(conferenceInfoButton)


    conferenceInfoButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.conferenceInfoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(conferenceIntoButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    scrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 0)
    containerView.anchor(top:scrollView.topAnchor, left: scrollView.leftAnchor, bottom: scrollView.bottomAnchor, right: scrollView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: 0)

conferenceInfoButton.anchor(top: locationLabel.bottomAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 25, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 300, height: 50)
```

conferenceInfoButton.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(self.scrollView.centerXAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
      }

```
@objc
func conferenceIntoButtonPressed() {
    debugPrint("hello, its me")
}
```

No matter what i have tried regarding these settings listed above, I cannot get this message to print!

Comment: in the code that you show, `conferenceInfoButton` is not even added to the view hierarchy.. show the whole code

Comment: no it's added to containerView

Comment: try to replace scrollView.bringSubview(toFront: conferenceInfoButton) with  containerView.bringSubview(toFront: conferenceInfoButton) or comment it as it makes no sense if only scrollview is a subview of the VC

Comment: @Sh_Khan unfortunately I have tried this again with no such luck...

Comment: I don't see constraints for the button ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add constraint to the button

```
conferenceInfoButton.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: containerView.frame.width, height: 0)
```

Comment: I modified this, so that I am using a different top anchor (a sibling element nested in the container view). simply adding the left and right references to `containerView.leftAnchor` solved this problem! thank you!

Comment: yes, modify it as you want , I only wanted to remind you to add  constraints  to the button